# Pyspark Convert RDD of tuples to Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have a rdd of tuples where the first two lines look like this:

```
[[('n', 12.012457082117459), ('s', 0.79112758892014912)],
[('t', 3.6243409329763652),('vn', 3.6243409329763652),('n', 52.743253562212828),('v', 11.644347760553064)]]
```

In each tuple, the first value,  e.g: 'n','s','t', is the desired column name, and the second value, e.g: 12.012, 0.7911.... is the desired values for each column. However, in each list(row) of rdd, we can see that not all column names are there. For example, in the first row, only

```
'n', 's'
```

appeared, while there is no

```
's'
```

in the second row. So I want to convert this rdd to a dataframe, where the values should be 0 for columns that do not show up in the original tuple. In other words, the first two rows might look like this:

```
n     s      t       vn     omitted.....
12    0.79   0       0      ..... 
52    0      3.62    3.62    .......
```

I tried following:

```
row = Row('l','eng','q','g','j','b','nt','z','n','d','f','i','k','s','vn','nz','v','nrt','tg','nrfg','t','ng','zg','a')
df = tup_sum_data.map(row).toDF()
```

Where strings in Row() are my desired column names. But i got following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/1/Documents/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _infer_type(obj)
968         try:
--> 969             return _infer_schema(obj)
970         except TypeError:

/Users/1/Documents/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _infer_schema(row)
991     else:
--> 992         raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
993 

TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'numpy.float64'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/1/Documents/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _infer_type(obj)
968         try:
--> 969             return _infer_schema(obj)
970         except TypeError:

/Users/1/Documents/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _infer_type(obj)
969             return _infer_schema(obj)
970         except TypeError:
--> 971             raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))
972 
973 

TypeError: not supported type: <class 'tuple'>
```

Some lines in the error codes are omitted. Could anyone help me figure out how to deal with this? Thank you !

**UPDATE**
I converted data types from np.float64 to float, and there is no error. However, the dataframe does not look like what I wanted; it looked like this:

```
+--------------------+
|                   l|
+--------------------+
|[[n,12.0124570821...|
|[[t,3.62434093297...|
|[[a,0.44628710262...|
|[[n,16.7534769832...|
|[[n,17.6017774340...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

So can anyone help me how to get a correctly formatted dataframe? Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *

data_frame_schema = StructType([
    StructField("n", FloatType()),
    StructField("s", FloatType()),
    StructField("t", FloatType()),
    StructField("v", FloatType()),
    StructField("vn", FloatType())
])

raw_list = [[('n', 12.012457082117459), ('s', 0.79112758892014912)], \
[('t', 3.6243409329763652),('vn', 3.6243409329763652),('n', 52.743253562212828),('v', 11.644347760553064)]]

raw_rdd = sc.parallelize(raw_list)

# dict_to_row = lambda d: Row(n=d.get("n"), s=d.get("s"), t=d.get("t"), v=d.get("v"), vn=d.get("vn"))
dict_to_row = lambda d: Row(n=d.get("n", 0.0), s=d.get("s", 0.0), t=d.get("t", 0.0), v=d.get("v", 0.0), vn=d.get("vn", 0.0))

row_rdd = raw_rdd.map(lambda l: dict_to_row(dict(l)))
df = spark.createDataFrame(row_rdd, data_frame_schema)
df.show()
```

Pasting the above into the pyspark shell yields output:

```
+---------+----------+--------+---------+--------+
|        n|         s|       t|        v|      vn|
+---------+----------+--------+---------+--------+
|12.012457|0.79112756|     0.0|      0.0|     0.0|
| 52.74325|       0.0|3.624341|11.644348|3.624341|
+---------+----------+--------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. By the way, is there any method to convert null to 0?

Comment: Just updated answer to use 0.0 for missing values. Does that work?

Comment: Worked great! Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Your answer gave me an idea this RDD format into a pyspark dataframe:
```
[('ADBDBAE7-C5DD-4CC8-90A1', {'im'}), ('CB23F740-F450-4D30-9B23', {'pr'})]
```
Solution:
```python
row_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(did=x[0],profile=list(x[1])))
df = spark.createDataFrame(row_rdd)